# Subscript Out Of Range when accessing Sheet in another opened Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I want to reference to the first opened Workbook. 2 workbooks are open: one that is calling the macro to execute, and the workbook which contains the macro. Somehow, the code runs smoothly very often. But sometimes, there occurs a referencing error when accessing data in the first opened workbook: Subscript Out Of Range.

On this line, the error occurs:

```
Set mastersheet = Workbooks(1).Sheets("Setting")
```

So there should be two workbooks in the collection. What am I overseeing? Please keep in mind, that the first opened workbook doesn't have a fixed name, so the name of the open workbook changes. The second Workbook, the workbook which contains the macro to execute, doesn't change it's name.

Comment: I'd put `Debug.print Workbooks(1).Name` before that line and wait until you reproduce the error, then see what the immediate window says. Also keep in mind that if you have any personal macros setup, `Workbooks(1)` will always be `PERSONAL.xlsb`, which would throw off your indexing...

Comment: Probably a better idea to identify your workbook by name instead of by number: `Workbooks("MyWorkbookName").Sheets("Setting")`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ He says that his workbook doesn't have a fixed name, so he can't use that solution (I think?).

Comment: @dwirony well but relying on a workbooks number is ever worse I think. So he will need a workaround to identify his workbook properly, which is either by name or by reference like `Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(filename)`

Comment: @rwatermelon How are these workbooks opened? By VBA or manually?

Comment: Can't he just use `If Workbook.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then`?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yes I agree... surely there's something *similar* about the workbook names, so he could use `InStr` to find the right workbook then `Set` it...

Comment: I am looking for a way to reference the correct filename. 2 files are opened. if the file contains a sheet with the name "Setting", it is the correct file.

Comment: the report workbook (to which I want to reference) is opened by a scheduled task. The CommonMacro (which asks for the reference) is opened by VBA (sometimes. Mostly its throwing an error). The CommonMacro is stored in the Documents folder.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you don't provide more code or any information about what kind of code "container" the macro is in. The following solution assumes the macro is in a Worksheet or Workbook code container (`Sheet1` or `ThisWorkbook` in the VBA Editor, for example).

It's possible to get the workbook from the code container. If the code is in a Worksheet code container, then use `Me.Parent`. If it's in `ThisWorkbook` use `Me`. These containers are actually *classes* that represent the Worksheet / the Workbook object. So `Me` refers to that object. The parent of a Worksheet is its workbook.

So a `Workbook` object is set to its container workbook. Then the open workbooks are looped in a `For...Each` and the workbook is tested whether it's the same as the code container workbook, or if it's another. If it's another, then the loop is exited. `Debug.Print` shows the result (two different names) and demonstrates how to continue to work with the separate workbook objects.

```
Sub GetOtherWorkbook()
    Dim wbWithMacro As Workbook
    Dim wbOther As Workbook, wb As Workbook

    Set wbWithMacro = Me.Parent 'Assumes macro is in a "Sheet" code container
    'Set wbWithMacro = Me   'Assumes macro is in "ThisWorkbook" code container
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If Not wb Is Me Then
            Set wbOther = wb
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Debug.Print wbWithMacro.Name, wbOther.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: The CommonMacro resides in a module, it's called Module1. I don't think I can use this code you provided? Therefor I would need ThisWorkbook or ActiveWorkbook to reference between them, but I want to avoid this approach. Thank you for your tips!!

Comment: Why not simply use `ThisWorkbook`? That always refers to the workbook in which the code resides (I actually should have thought of that, before). You don't want ActiveWorkbook because that could be anything.

Comment: Because ThisWorkbook would reference the wrong one I think. ThisWorkbook is the workbook, where the code is executed, but I want to access the sheet called "Setting", and therefor I need to check, if the Workbook contains a sheet called "Setting", so I can reference correctly. I also try to avoid .Select and .Activate.

Comment: The CommonMacro resides in the Module1 - Container

Comment: @RWatermelon If only two workbooks are open, as you say, then one will be the code container the other will not. It's not clear from your problem description in which workbook "Settings" is, but it's either in `ThisWorkbook` or the other one - which can be determined using the logic in my answer (the loop). Or use PEH's logic. But both approaches will work...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following to find the `Setting` worksheet:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FindSettingWorksheet()
    Dim MasterSheet As Worksheet

    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Workbooks 'loop through all open workbooks
        On Error Resume Next 'stop error reporting
        Set MasterSheet = wb.Worksheets("Setting") 'if this throws an error it's the wrong workbook
        On Error GoTo 0 're-enable error reporting
        If Not MasterSheet Is Nothing Then Exit For 'if we found the setting worksheet we can exit/stop
    Next wb


    If Not MasterSheet Is Nothing Then 'test if we found it
        Debug.Print MasterSheet.Name
    Else
        Debug.Print "Settings not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems good, I will give it a try. I hope the referencing works then and it doesn't throw me the Subscript Out Of Range again. I will keep you informed. Thank you!

Comment: Small detail: when the correct WB is found, the for loop exits without resetting the error handler.

Comment: @chris neilsen: What if I assign a variable containing the correct Workbooks.Name instead of Exit For?

Comment: @RWatermelon better approach is 
    `For Each wb In Workbooks 
        Set MasterSheet = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next 
        Set MasterSheet = wb.Worksheets("Setting")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not MasterSheet Is Nothing Then Exit For
    Next wb`

Comment: Can you tell me how can I assign the right filename to a variable? I don't receive any value when I assign it and throw it out with a MessageBox

I also want to call this filename from other subs and functions in my macro, so I can assign the filename correctly

Comment: This question has nothing to do with your original question. Please open up a new question for that and provide proper information about what you are trying and where your difficulties are. We cannot answer questions in comments.